# Get an element of a set without iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash, set

Suppose you want an element that may be in a set. You don't have the element itself, but you do know how to work out its hash. How do you get the element?

Here's my code so far:

```
import random

class A(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.rand = random.random()


    def __hash__(self):
        return hash('A{}'.format(self.x))


    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__hash__()==other.__hash__()


# create many A instances
N = 10**7
s = set()
for x in xrange(N):
    s.add(A(x))


# test some ways to find a particular A
def find_A_given_x(x):
    """ Iterate over s to find A """
    for a in s:
        if a.x == x:
            return a


def find_A_given_x_without_iterating_s(x):
    """ Try to use hash to get the element??? """
    raise NotImplemented('I don\'t know how to do this!')
```

Comment: oh yeh. damn. how then does (a in s) work? if it only has the hash function to go by, and two distinct a's collide, how could it know?

Comment: The hash *and* equality testing are used. If the hash collided, the hash is *perturbed* (processed to produce a new slot with smaller and smaller steps) and the next object at that new slot is tested, etc.

Comment: You may want to study how a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) works in general.

Comment: Right. This makes sense. I better use a dictionary.

Comment: this questions meaning : My laptop got ***MemoryError***. :)))

Comment: actually, mine did too. I'm not sure what that's about. That's another question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't retrieve an object from a set by its hash. Note that a hash is not required to be unique! Sets are not designed to retrieve specific individual elements (other than returning an *arbitrary* element from the set), in any case.

The only option you have is to *iterate over all elements of the set* and test if the hash matches, and accept that there may be multiple such matches.

At any rate, hashing is used to reduce an object to a slot in the hash table; if that slot is occupied by a different object (`tested_object == object_in_slot` is false) the hash is processed to produce a new slot, etc. The underlying hash table is an implementation detail and not otherwise exposed to introspection or other applications.

Comment: oh yeh. damn. how then does (a in s) work? if it only has the hash function to go by, and two distinct a's collide, how could it know?